# Wrong output when trying to print out mouse position

Tags: python, debugging, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a function which continually prints out the mouse position constantly until stopped.
import pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

print('Press CTRL + "c" to stop')

while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end = ' ')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end = '', flush = True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
        break
```

The expected output should look something like this:

*X: 265 Y:634*
*only one line continually refreshed*

But this is what I'm getting instead:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:  665 Y:  587

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:  665 Y:  587

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:  665 Y:  587

XXXXXXXXXX:  718 Y:  598

XXXXXXXXXXXX: 1268 Y:  766

*remove the \b characters*
    import pyautogui

```
print('Press CTRL + "c" to stop')

while True:
try:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
    print(positionStr)
    print('\b' * len(positionStr), end = '', flush = True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone')
    break
```

*X:  830 Y:  543*

*X:  830 Y:  543*

*X:  830 Y:  543*

*X:  830 Y:  543*

Done

Comment: What is the output if you do not print the '\b' characters?

Comment: Updated the results to match. It got rid of the repeating 'x' s, but still isn't flushing

Comment: What do you mean it isn't flushing?

Comment: Not constantly deleting itself and reprinting so it gets something like this X: 265 Y:634

Comment: I still do not understand how what you want differs from what you get. The output contains the x and y coordinated just as you describe.

Comment: The output is deleted only because you say to do so. If you do not want anything deleted, don't do it. (Note this is what the '\b' character does.)

Comment: But it wasn't actually getting deleted, and for some reason X was printing out an arbitrary number of times in a single calling. But that part of the issue was sorted out.

Comment: '\b' is the backspace character, so characters were being deleted in your original version. The arbitrary number of X's was from a lack of deleting

Comment: It will help a lot if you edit your question to show a specific example of his you expect the output to look. Out else explain in detail what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You could print the line with a Carriage Return, e.g.:

```
print(positionStr + '\r'),
```

Like so, the next line will replace the existing one. And you'll always see one line updated with the new mouse position.

The full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyautogui

print('Press CTRL + "c" to stop')

while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr + '\r'),
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
        break
```

**EDIT**

As said in the comments below, this solution will work on Unix platform but was not tested on others. It should break due to the different line ending conventions. Thanks to @Code-Apprentice who's pointed it out.

**RE-EDIT**

Since the comments of OP and Code-Apprentice, I tried to fix the script like this, and it works as expected:

```
import pyautogui

print('Press CTRL + "c" to stop')

while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end=' ')
        print('\b' * (len(positionStr) + 1), end='')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
        break
```

Comment: @volcano Thanks for the edit but the coma comes after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, messed that up. Need more sleep :-)

Comment: Will the '\r' start the next print on the same line? What if the next line to print has fewer characters? Is the behavior platform independent because of different line ending conventions?

Comment: It actually helped. However, it doesn't seem to be deleting at the end and just prints out all values successively like in the usual print calling. I messed with it a little and now python crashes whenever I run it. Lol

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Yes, the `'\r'` will start the next print on the same line. It works in this case because of the `rjust(4)` who makes these strings always the same length. For the last question, I don't understand. You mean with different versions of python ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber I mean with different operating systems

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Ok, I tested it on Unix. On other platform, I guest it will break, as you said, because of different line ending conventions. I admit it's not the best solution... Will edit the answer. Thanks for the feed back !

Comment: The rjust(4) assume that no number is longer than 4 digits. This is probably a safe assumption in this case. If not, then there will be some additional characters on subsequent prints.

Comment: @user7032374 see my RE-EDIT answer, it should work now.

Comment: @ Adrien Leber It seems to be crashing the shell for some reason. I'm on windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, no errors. Just hangs as soon as I run the program until a while after I KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 1):

You are not backspacing enough characters. You forgot to account for the extra space "end" character.  Of course you should be able to leave out the `end` parameter entirely.

Comment: So how would I increase the number of backspaces I make, should I make it len(positionString) + 1 or something to that effect?

Comment: @user7032374 that should do the trick. Or, as I said in the answer, remove the `end` parameter from the preceding call.

Comment: So I got rid of both the ends, but it still doesn't erase the lines. e.g

Comment: i got rid of both the ends but it's still not deleting the previous line i.e X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515

X:  822 Y:  515


Done

Comment: @user7032374 please edit your question to show your current code