# PyAutoGui repeats incorrect mouse position

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm starting to learn PyAutoGui and I'm reading the docs and watching tutorials. For now, I'm simply attempting to get my mouse's position on the screen, but it continually repeats the same coordinates no matter how I move my mouse. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058078/pyautogui-position-return-the-same-value-always) had a similar problem, but was never answered. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121925/wrong-output-when-trying-to-print-out-mouse-position) also had a similar problem, yet the solution did not work for me.

According to the docs (and other stack overflow posts), the correct code to get the second-by-second X-Y position of the mouse is:

```
import pyautogui 
import time 

print(pyautogui.size())
while True: 
    print (pyautogui.position())
    time.sleep(1)
```

The printout looks like this:

```
Size(width=3840, height=1080)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
Point(x=70, y=250)
```

That point X/70 Y/250 is repeated into infinity no matter how I move my mouse. I'm using VSCode & WSL2 for this. Restarting, uninstalling & reinstalling modules don't seem to help either. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

I should mention this alternate solution, implementing a carriage return, doesn't work either(below), nor does the displayMousePosition() method

```
while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end=' ')
        print('\b' * (len(positionStr) + 1), end='')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
        break
```

Comment: What happens when you just run it without the while loop? Does it still print that same position?

Comment: It does print that same position if I don't run a loop - I've tried it a bunch of ways now.

I found out that if I use the .moveTo(x, y) method, it will actually print out the position that was 'moved to' despite my mouse not actually every moving. 

While using the .displayMousePosition(), the screenshot associated with this method is totally black. Still trying to figure it out!

Comment: What os are you using??

Comment: I'm on a PC using Windows 11. I found out that If I want to use any GUI automation libraries, I'll have to run them not through WSL & ubuntu like I was, but in the native Windows & powershell environment

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was running this using WSL on a PC. It turns out GUI automation libraries cannot be run in the linux subsystem, but need to be run in the native windows environment (i.e. use powershell for Windows users, NOT ubuntu/WSL).